Tesseract does not recognize Clean Image from Cropped Image (Car Permit Reader)
I am trying to read car permits area, but tesseract doesn't read some areas completely.
Here is my code and processes:

Firstly, align image with template. (I will add the template).
Set image dpi with below code.

Code:
def set_image_dpi(file_path):
    IMAGE_SIZE = 1800
    im = Image.open(file_path)
    length_x, width_y = im.size
    factor = max(1, int(IMAGE_SIZE / length_x))
    size = factor * length_x, factor * width_y
    # size = (1800, 1800)
    im_resized = im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.jpg')
    temp_filename = temp_file.name
    im_resized.save(temp_filename, dpi=(300, 300))
    return temp_filename


Then I remove noise and crop the confident boxes:

code:
def remove_noise(image):
return cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(image, None, 10, 10, 7, 15)

if box.conf[0] > 0.20:
    class_name = classes_names[int(box.cls[0])]
    custom = False
    custom_config_str = ""
    [x1, y1, x2, y2] = box.xyxy[0]
    # convert to int
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
    cropped = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    cropped = remove_noise(cropped)
    cropped = cv2.cvtColor(cropped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # blur
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(cropped, (0, 0), sigmaX=99, sigmaY=99)

    # divide
    cropped = cv2.divide(cropped, blur, scale=255)

Then tesseract code:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
        cropped,
        config=None if custom != True else "-psm 6,
        lang="tur")

Here is the saved results that I can share and raw text results.  What can cause the misrecognizing text and  what processes I can add to get clearer results? Because the images are really clean, but many sometimes I can not get any data from them.
 text: DJTICARIADI \n
 text: DIMARKASI \nRENALLI
 text: /Y.3/KULLANIMAMACI \n YOLCUNAKLİ-HUSUSİİ

